# crontab doesn't create screen session

Tags: cron

I am trying to use

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS nfc /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/npm run --prefix /home/pi/nfc/ dev
```

to run my script in `/home/pi/nfc/` on startup. Sadly after rebooting, I don't see any started screens (using `screen -ls`). If I use the command (without the `@reboot`) normally it works (`screen -ls` list my screen).

`reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS test` works as expected.

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` shows me `Mar 25 17:22:05 pi CRON[509]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/screen -dmS nfc /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/npm run --prefix /home/pi/nfc/ dev)`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance that the npm command exits? If you invoke screen like that, it will close the screen after the child process exits.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the assumption that your npm scripts exits at some point, resulting in the screen session terminating.

You can avoid that by running some command afterwards to keep screen "busy":

```
screen -dmS foo sleep 10s
```

will exit after 10 seconds, while

```
screen -dmS bar bash -c 'sleep 10s; bash'
```

will start a bash shell after sleep and prevent `screen` from terminating.

---

In your crontab that would look as following:

`@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS nfc bash -c '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/npm run --prefix /home/pi/nfc/ dev; exec bash'`

---

If your intention is not to interact with the script, but to keep the log output of your `npm` script, you could as well redirect the output to a logfile instead of using `screen`:

`@reboot /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/npm run --prefix /home/pi/nfc/ dev >> /home/pi/npmscript.log`